I would like to download file in excel with selenium edge web driver in specific custom folder in java selenium
The excel sheet should download in the custom directory, but it downloads to default(Default Downlaods) folder.
HashMap<String, Object> edgePrefs = new HashMap<>(); 
edgePrefs.put("download.default_directory", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\Download-Files");
edgePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
edgePrefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1); // Set EdgeOptions EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", edgePrefs);

I have tried this way, but setExperimentalOption shows an error:

The method setExperimentalOption(String, HashMap<String, Object>) is undefined for the type EdgeOptions


Why do you think that the method setExperimentalOption(String, HashMap<String, Object>) should be defined for the type EdgeOptions?

You might want to look at the doc for EdgeDriver, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=java
